# How to connect to port using pyserial?

Tags: python, pyserial

I tried to connect to `CashCode VAULT1500` Bill Validator.
I'd connected it to Windows machine and working in `Debian` `VmBox` virtual machine. There how i connect COM port with `CashCode` into `VMBox`:

[image: VMBox screenshot]

On debian i check port name:

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

Got:

```
/dev/ttyS3
```

Now i tried to connect to port like in example https://github.com/ubombi/cashcode_ccnet/tree/master/ccnet:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS3', baudrate=9600, timeout=None,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE)
t = ser.read(3)
```

But no answer here.
What can i miss on `VMBox` settings or code?

Comment: Does the user that you're running have rights to the device (ls -l /dev/ttyS3)?

Comment: Connecting to a serial device, and immediately trying to read from it, is not likely to accomplish anything - how is the device supposed to know that it is supposed to send something?  You probably need to send it a status request message, or some other sort of command that will produce a response for you to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the COM port name directly?

```py
ser = serial.Serial('COM4')
print(ser.name)
ser.read(3)
```